# Can I use JsDoc for my .css and .scss file?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsdoc

I am working on the react application Where I need the documentation for the .cs and .scss files.

For the source code of my component  I am using the JsDoc for generating document. But I want to use the same for the .css and .scss file also. Is it possible ? If not then What is the best solution to create the document for the .css and .scss files ?

Comment: Have you tried http://sassdoc.com/ ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, aside the fact JSDoc is prefixed with 'js', if you see in detail how jsdoc works, basically they parse the javascript file creating AST using [espree](https://github.com/eslint/espree), that would not work for CSS/SCSS files.

I would recommend [sassdoc.com](http://sassdoc.com/) for SCSS/SASS files.

Comment: Unreachable link, that answer has been deleted from SO

Comment: Updated, I removed the link, the StackOverflow thread just disappeared.